# R- jupyter notebooks: text error when plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting with ggplot/baseplot in jupyter notebooks, using a R-Kernel (and the package repr is loaded). However no text/ only weirdly positioned f's are displayed. Any idea what the reason is?

See for ggplot:

```
data("iris")
scatter <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) 
scatter + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
 xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
 ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width")
```

[image]

Same is the case for normal base R plots:

```
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=3)
options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = "image/svg+xml")
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, main = "blabla")
```

[image]

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /home/janinek/.conda/envs/R-3.5.1/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /home/janinek/.conda/envs/R-3.5.1/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C                 LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] repr_0.15.0    ggplot2_3.0.0  reshape2_1.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18     compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.3.0     plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] bindr_0.1.1      base64enc_0.1-3  tools_3.5.1      digest_0.6.15   
 [9] uuid_0.1-2       jsonlite_1.5     evaluate_0.11    tibble_1.4.2    
[13] gtable_0.2.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.1      IRdisplay_0.5.0 
[17] IRkernel_0.8.12  bindrcpp_0.2.2   withr_2.1.2      stringr_1.3.1   
[21] dplyr_0.7.6      grid_3.5.1       tidyselect_0.2.4 glue_1.3.0      
[25] R6_2.2.2         pbdZMQ_0.3-3     purrr_0.2.5      magrittr_1.5    
[29] scales_0.5.0     htmltools_0.3.6  assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2
[33] labeling_0.3     stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0   
[37] crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. Think the error has to do something with the jupyter notebooks settings, as such, I did not think that the code was of relevance. But, I have adjusted the post and added the `SessionInfo()`

Comment: We may need to see your Python environment as well. Running v 2.7 or v 3.4+? Try updating ipython and jupyter modules. Check versions: `conda list ipython` or `jupyter --version`. I don't use any conda distributions, so cannot help in this regard.